# SQL Server: Create Nonclustered Index without giving a name to it

Tags: sql-server, indexing, alter-table, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I use SQL Server 2008.

I am trying to create a nonclustered index on my table. I want to check if there exists a way to create this without giving a name to the index.

For e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (Date_ datetime NOT NULL, ID_ varchar(10) NOT NULL, Value_)
```

When I add a PK to this table, I do not specify the name of that key. For e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Date_ ASC, ID_ ASC)
```

Is it possible to do something similar to create a nonclustered index without specifying a name?

For e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE #mytable ADD NONCLUSTERED INDEX (Date_, Value_)   -- FAILS!!!
```

The only command I know is

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX *keyname* ON #mytable (Date_, Value_)
```

Comment: No, there's no support for creating an index without giving it a name - and **why on earth** would you want to do that anyway? How would you manage such an index (rebuilt it or reorganize it, when needed; drop it, when no longer needed)....

Comment: If front end code will execute multiple instances of SP in parallel then SP will fail stating that object already exists. You should never name indexes on temp table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create a non-clustered index without a name, the syntax is quite clear:

```
CREATE [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] INDEX index_name
```

> index_name
>   Is the name of the index. Index names must be unique within a table or
>   view but do not have to be unique within a database. Index names must
>   follow the rules of identifiers.

[CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

> The database object name is referred to as its identifier. Everything
>   in Microsoft SQL Server can have an identifier. Servers, databases,
>   and database objects, such as tables, views, columns, indexes,
>   triggers, procedures, constraints, and rules, can have identifiers.
>   **Identifiers are required for most objects**, but are optional for some
>   objects such as constraints.

[Database Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

After create temp table execute dynamic sequel with guid as index name

DECLARE @NewId VARCHAR(64) = REPLACE(NEWID(),'-','');

EXEC('CREATE INDEX IX_'+@NewId+' ON #Table (ColA,ColB) INCLUDE (ColZ)');